# Cannot connect via SSH after I added AllowGroups

Tags: ssh, putty, ubuntu-16.04

I was able to connect to my server using PuTTY SSH but from security standpoint I did the following and now I am not able to connect. My goal was to restrict SSH access to only user accounts that should have it.

1. I created a group dedicated to SSH:

   ```
   sudo addgroup sshlogin
   ```
2. I added the following to the file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

   ```
   AllowGroups sshlogin
   ```
3. I added user to the group:

   ```
   sudo adduser username sshlogin
   ```
4. I restarted the service:

   ```
   sudo systemctl restart sshd.service
   ```

After restarting SSH service I am not able to connect to the server using PuTTY. What is wrong? How to fix this?

Comment: Did any of the commands return error or warning? When you try to connect, do you get the login prompt? and then cannot log in as `username`? Or no prompt as if `sshd` wasn't there? Any error messages? Is the old connection still open? If it's not, can you log into the server by any other channel? or are you cut off completely? Please respond by [edit]ing the question.

Comment: Could this be a simple mishap? Did you run all the commands 1-4 on the same host? Are you sure you are connecting as "username"? Do you have a `DenyGroups` which could have overridden your `AllowGroups` setting?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your all reply. i reinstall ssh and now it is working for me. it had being nice if i knew the root cause of it.

Thank you all.